# Drupal DB Query

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules

I have a problem with a custom query in drupal:

`$brief = db_query("SELECT * FROM`dr_wiwe_profile_values`WHERE`fid`= 16 AND`uid`= 266");`

This query returns resource(286) of type (mysql result) resource(562) of type (mysql result) .

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: Nothing's wrong, db_query actually returns a query result object. What do you expect?

Comment: I expect an array with values.

Answer (score 1):

loop over the db resource object

```
$dbh = db_query("SELECT * FROM dr_wiwe_profile_values WHERE fid=16 AND uid=266");
$results = array();
while($row = db_fetch_array($dbh)){
  $results[] = $row;
}
```